# Determining when objects are ready. Should I be using events?

Tags: javascript, events, design-patterns

I am programming a canvas racing game, and planned to use events to determine when each game object is initialised and ready to use. First I tried to add event listeners to my objects, but realised they can only be attached to html elements. As a workaround I added a listener to the window object instead.

I would appreciate advice on whether I should be using events for this problem at all, and if there are any common patterns/methods I should look at? I was going to read up on the Observer pattern, does this seem suitable for this scenario?

Code snippets below show what I am doing at the moment. When all items of the Track object are loaded, it dispatches an event which is caught by an event listener attached to the window object.

Main:

```
function game() {
  var loadCount = 0;
  var itemsToLoad  = 10; 

  window.addEventListener("finishedLoading", itemLoaded, false);      
  function itemLoaded(event) {
    loadCount++;
    if(loadCount >= itemsToLoad)
    {
      gameStateFunction = title;
    }
  }
}
```

Track object:

```
function Track(name, bgTileSheet) {  
  this.backgroundImage = new Image();
  this.itemsLoaded = 0;
  this.itemsToLoad = 3;
  this.loadedEvent = new CustomEvent("finishedLoading", {
    detail: {
      objectType: "track"
    },
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: false
  });

  this.centerPath = null;
}

Track.prototype.updateLoadProgress = function() {
  this.itemsLoaded++;
  if(this.itemsLoaded >= this.itemsToLoad)
  {
    dispatchEvent(this.loadedEvent);
  }
};

Track.prototype.init = function() {
  //calls loadItems() when XML data is ready
};

Track.prototype.loadItems = function() {
  this.loadBackground();
  this.loadMapDimensions();
  this.loadPaths();
};

Track.prototype.loadBackground = function() {
  var self = this;
  this.backgroundImage.addEventListener("load", 
    function() {
      self.updateLoadProgress();
    }, 
    false);     
  this.backgroundImage.src = Track.TILESHEET_DIR + this.bgTileSheet;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I would say events are the way to go with something like this. It's just that you'll have to loosen your definition of events from being those solely attachable to HTML elements.

The majority of patterns you'd end up using for this sort of thing - observer, subscriber, mediator, whatever - will use a contrived form of events in one sense of another.

One thing you might want to look into is jQuery's deferred objects. These are often associated with AJAX but can also be used with contrived, subjective events in very effective ways.

I wrote [a blog post](http://www.mitya.co.uk/blog/2012/Apr/Non-AJAX-use-for-jQuerys-deferred-objects-207) this on this some months ago showing a technique for this.

Here's a quick sample:

```
function SomeClass() {
    this.ready = false;
    this.deferred = $.Deferred();
}
SomeClass.prototype.makeReady = function() {
    this.ready = true;
    this.deferred.resolve();
}
var myInstance = new SomeClass();

//listen for ready
$.when(myInstance.deferred).done(function() { alert('object is ready!'); });

//after a while, let's say we're ready
setTimeout(function() { myInstance.makeReady(); }, 2000);
```

The timeout here is just a simulation of your real environment where you would set up the object - do AJAX requests, other code, whatever.

Finally, while you indeed can't attach events to objects directly, you can attach objects to object properties via [getters/setters](http://www.mitya.co.uk/blog/2012/Mar/JavaScript-getters-and-setters-varying-approaches-204).